# Why does the browser returns undefined before the needed text?

Tags: javascript

So the task is to use the provided string and create a new one, but using UpperCase
Here is my code:

```
let str = 'i am in the easycode';
let newString;

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   newString += str[i].toUpperCase();
}
console.log(newString);
```

Console shows 'undefinedI AM IN THE EASYCODE'
I am not sure why the undefines popped out and what to do to fix it.

I believe this issue is related to the fact the newString variable was defined in global score while I manipulating with that inside the loop.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're concatenating to `newString`. `newString` starts out as *what value*…?

Comment: First, initialize newString like this: let newString='';

Comment: if you set your variable newString = '', is not be undefined at the beggining

Comment: You need to initialize newString before you concatenate char to it

Comment: This is not [tag:undefined-behavior]. This behaviour is very well defined. Please read the descriptions of the tags you use. Spamming tags or using improper tags is often rewarded with downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming a variable "str" or "newSring" doesn't necessarily make it a String, just like naming a variable "num" doesn't make it a Number. The name of a variable doesn't infer a type as far as the language is concerned.

JavaScript is loosely typed. When you say `let str` you are just creating a variable that is very literally `undefined` in both value and type.

You then try to add `undefined` and something whose value **is** a String, and the language rules cause that to evaluate to what you are seeing.

Instead, set the value of `newString` to an empty String:

```
let newString = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code like this:

```
let str = 'i am in the easycode';
const value = str.toUpperCase();
```

this method uppercase the whole letter

add the sting definition:

```
let newString = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because newString value is 'undefined'. And during first interation you adding up "undefined" and "I". 
You can use toUpperCase like so

```
str.toUpperCase()
```

No need to iterate through letters

Answer (score 0):

Assign an empty string to the `newString` variable.

Change:

```
let newString;
```

to:

```
let newString="";
```